# How do I encode/decode jpg image to upload ONLY using "urllib.request.Request"

Tags: python, python-3.x, jpeg, image-uploading

I'm experiencing problems with image not being encoded properly in my custom multipart-form/data being posted. 
After sending out the HTTP POST packet, I noticed the bytes representing the image is completely different. I did this comparison by capturing data packets for a working scenario (using the web browser) and using my python app.

There's no issues otherwise with how the multipart-form body is constructed, it's just that the image not being encoded properly for the body.

Here's what I did to open the image and prep it to be sent out:

```
image_data=(open('plane.jpg',mode='rb').read()) ## image_data is the jpeg in bytes                ------------- fist bytes
body.append(str(image_data))   ## coverting the data to a string such that it can be appended to the body array.  ------ bytes to string
body.append(CRLF)
body.append('--' + boundary + '--')
body.append(CRLF)
body=''.join(body)

## starting the post
unicode_data = body.encode('utf-8',errors='ignore')  ## --------string encoded
multipart_header['content-length']=len(unicode_data)
req = urllib.request.Request('http://localhost/api/image/upload', data=unicode_data, headers=multipart_header) ## Packet sent here and the image section of the unicode_data looks wrong but the other sections look good.
```

Image being uploaded: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=5aq3w6&s=6

So what is the correct way to encode this image and append it as part of the body to be sent? I don't want to use any apis other than the ones that came with python 3.3. and would like to stay within urllib and urllib2
I tried appending the byte version of the image to the body but apparently string arrays can only contain strings which is why I created a new string with the image in bytes; I think this is where it goes down hill.

Thanks help is much appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand why you use utf-8 to encode image data, it's not a text string, there might be errors during the encoding process. If you worry about the request object can't deal with raw bytes, that won't be necessary.

Comment: I did it because the body (data) being sent is an array of strings. I'm adding the image to this array and then flattening it to a string object for urllib.request. I think you're right I should just create a byte string from the beginning. Problem with that is it doesn't have *.append() function and also doesn't have *.join functions so it's not easy to create the multi-part form body. I'll have to look into how to create a string of bytes and how to append to it thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Tnx I fixed it by using bytearray and bytearray.expand.